# Symfony 3 FOS Rest + JMS Serializer groups

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

My `composer.json` (part of it):

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.1"
    }
}
```

I have some entities which I'd like to return partial data for the list action and complete for the find action. For so, I have these files:

Product.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="represented")
* @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("ALL")
*/
class Product
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
    * @var string
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, length=48)
    */
    protected $name;

    /**
    * @var Group
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="products")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $group;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setGroup(Group $group)
    {
        $this->group = $group;
    }

    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->group;
    }
}
```

ProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;

class ProductController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
    * @Get("/product", name="list_products")
    */
    public function listAction()
    {
        $products = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
            ->findBy([], [ 'name' => 'ASC' ]);

        $view = $this->view($products);

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }

    /**
    * @Get("/product/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, name="get_product")
    */
    public function getAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $product = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
            ->find($id);

        if ( ! $product) {
            $error = [
                'error' => 'Product not found'
            ];

            $view = $this->view($error, 404);
        } else {
            $view = $this->view($product);
        }

        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to not show the `group` property on the list result. For this I have tried a few of approaches, mainly with groups.

1. Just use configure the group name for the properties I want to show
   on my list with `Groups({"List"})` and refer this group on the
   controller with `@View(serializerGroups={"List"})`. But this had no
   affect as all properties are visible.
2. Configure `@ExclusionPolicy("all")` for the entire entity didn't
   work as well.
3. In addition to ExclusionPolicy, `@Expose` to all properties I wanted
   to show in some or all groups, but that made all properties marked
   to be shown.

I also tried some more variants of these, but nothing that change the results.

Answer (score 3):

End of your controller action should not be only:

```
return $this->handleView($view);
```

But for getting a group or groups working you need to activate them. On top of the class you need to add FOSRest Context, not JMS context:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Context\Context;
```

and in the controller actions before returning view:

```
$view = $this->view($products, 200);
$context = new Context();
$context->setGroups(['list']);
$view->setContext($context);

return $this->handleView($view);
```

This will work for Symfony 3.2 and FOSRest 2.1 and 2.0.

Link for upgrading documentation for FOSRest:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/UPGRADING-2.0.md

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@Exclude` then this should work.  Another option I have used is to make a small addition to `config.yml`:

```
fos_rest:
    serializer:
        groups: ['Default']
```

This requires that the entity properties be in the group `Default` in order to be serialized.  If you have no `@Groups` annotation on a property then it will be in `Default`, but as soon as you add the `@Groups` annotation then it will no longer be in the `Default` group (unless you specifically add it.)

This allowed the default serialization process to include all the entity fields except for those with a `@Groups` annotation, and then elsewhere I could serialize with both `Default` and my other groups selected if I wanted everything to be included.

```
// Function in the Controller class
public function getAction(MyEntity $me) {
    // Use automatic serializer, only things in 'Default' group are included
    return $me;
}
```